# Cloudbees & Github: Error: Key already in use

Tags: deployment, github, public-key, cloudbees

I would like to push back the results from a build to github and I therefore use the Git publisher plugin. However, when I try to add the SSH public key from Cloudbees as a Deploy Key on Github then Github tells me: 'Key already in use' since it is also part of another repository.

I would like to know why I cannot use the same public key for multiple independent repositories?

[update]
The answers so far indicate that the question is unclear. Cloudbees generates a key pair and uses this on github, I've not found a way to create an alternate pair, so I am stuck with one pair.

I've added the public key to repo A so Cloudbees can pull from repo A. However, I want to use the same build to push to repo B. So it seems logical to add the same (my personal Cloudbees key) to to repo B so cloudbees can push to repo B as well.

However, on Github only a single repo can be using the deploy key:

> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on the server and grants access to a single repo on GitHub. This key is attached directly to the repo instead of to a user account.

So it is clear that the the public key cannot be attached to more than one repo. However, I can't think of a reason why this is the case?

Anybody?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github, (Error: Key already in use)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160774/github-error-key-already-in-use)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your ssh key for user, not repository, so you can use it for multiple github repositories. github don't allow using same key on multiple locations

Comment: I think it was clear from my question that that github forbids it; the question is: why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the key is used to identify the user. It's like you would only use a password to identify the user: if two users have the same password, how do you know which is which?

A key is supposed to be unique to a user.

You can, however, generate multiple keys on the same machine and configure git/ssh to [use a specific key](http://www.springloops.com/blog/git-config-for-mutiply-ssh-keys/) instead of the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (or other `id_*.pub` key).

Comment: A public key is password AND id, that is the beauty of PKI, so you cannot have another id with the same key. I cannot find a way for Cloudbees to generate another key, nor do I understand why this is required for a deploy key ...