# GitHub: How to get rid of a Phantom Key?

Tags: github

I generated my key on a Windows 11 machine. I have now attempted to add the key to my brand new MacBook. And I get the error,

> Key already in use.

Ok - so in an effort to solve the problem I deleted the repo and create a new repo with the same name. I get the same error.

The Github docs say:

> This error occurs when you try to add a key that's already been added to another account or repository.

**I have only ever had 1 repo and only 1 account.**

I have no idea where this is coming from. I am concerned that my account might have been compromised.

How do I get rid of this phantom key?

Answer (score 0):

The key should be listed in your [GitHub account profile/SSH section](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-11964/images/help/settings/ssh-add-ssh-key.png]

That is where you should be able to delete any previous registered key.

Comment: thanks for that. That is part of the mystery. I have checked this page and there is no record of a key on my account. Nevertheless, I am getting this error - "key already in use".  I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Vince Do you have any older account, or same account but with a different email you have changed since?

Comment: @Vince Maybe you already registered it as deploy key? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33642472/6309)